# Flutter web create issue in existing flutter app

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-web

I already have the flutter app, now I am adding support to flutter Web following [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/web) doc. I am getting the error on `flutter create .`

```
Ambiguous organization in existing files: {com.app.android.fluttermodule,com.app.android.flutterModule}. The --org command line argument must be
specified to recreate project.
```

I have mentioned `pubsec.yml`

```
  module:
    androidPackage: com.app.android.fluttermodule
    iosBundleIdentifier: com.app.android.flutterModule
```

Comment: check android & IOS package name

Comment: If I trying to change that it's not working

Comment: change android package name  from manifest and IOS package name from Xcode

Comment: I just change my ios bunddle id same as android package name and it works

Comment: I found that using dashes in the parent dir name will cause this, see my answer at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67317234/ambiguous-organization-in-existing-files-the-org-command-line-argume/72297865#72297865

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am getting this issue because of creating flutter web apps from existing flutter Android and iOS codebase,for this structure flutter web is not supported... We have to create a new flutter project for web

Comment: Then what the doc mean here
https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/web#add-web-support-to-an-existing-app

Comment: I added support to existing project, please have a look at my answer and try that out :)

Answer (score 72):

You can use this command

```
flutter create --org package_name .
```

Comment: What does the above command do? Why doesn't `flutter create .` work?

Comment: When I use this command with an existing project I get the following error:
"App_Flutter" is not a valid Dart package name.

Please note I'm trying to add a macOS version @SawThinkarNayHtoo

Answer (score 9):

You can add the app to the existing flutter project as well. Here are some steps that I followed

1: Create a new branch to not mess things up in existing branch if you are starting with flutter web for the first time.

2: `flutter channel master`

3: `flutter config --enable-web`: Now you may or may not see the new Dart SDK being downloaded.

4: `flutter create --org package_name .`: This will add the web files in your project.

5: `flutter devices`: You must see chrome listed now.

6: `flutter run -d chrome`: If you see something like project not configured for the web then try step 3 again and reopen your editor.

Comment: Hello Harshit, I follow your steps facing one error please help!
No devices found with name or id matching 'chrome'

Comment: hello, flutter create --org package_name . in this step if i entered correct package name also is not a valid Dart package name error showing.

Answer (score 6):

this worked for me.
you need to specify output directory too.
for the same flutterapp directory, use ./
hope this helps u :)

```
flutter create --org flutterappname ./
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I did for an existing project.

Step 1: Create a new folder named **web_project** or something in the existing project folder.

Step 2: Go to this folder in the terminal

Step 3: Run `flutter create --platforms web --org com.example.flutter .`

This step will create a new flutter project with a **web** folder in it

Step 4: Cut and paste the web folder in your existing project folder and delete the new project which in my case was **web_project**

Step 5: Run the project and you will see Chrome as a device in the devices menu

FYI: This is done on Flutter 2.2.0

Hope this will help you to add web support to your flutter project

Answer (score 2):

You jus add following line

```
flutter create --org FLUTTER_APP .
```

Answer (score 1):

we don't have to create a new project, we just need to pass the specific organization name.

```
 e.g: flutter create --org <<domain_keyword>> .
```

this happens because, during new project creation, we leave the domain as IDE suggested. which is "com.example.project_name" and during sign application, we need to change the domain and almost everyone change it.

Answer (score 1):

> Ambiguous organization in existing files: {com.app.android.fluttermodule,com.app.android.flutterModule}. The --org command line argument must be
> specified to recreate project.

It means there's different package names.

com.app.android.fluttermodule
com.app.android.flutterModule

One or some of your names contain lowercase m in ..android.fluttermodule and some uppercase M. Rename all to be the same and run `flutter create .` again.