# Ambiguous organization in existing files:{ .... }. The --org command line argument must be specified to recreate project

Tags: windows, flutter, android-studio, compilation

While trying to run my existing flutter app on windows, got the following exeption - "Exception: No Windows desktop project configured. See https://flutter.dev/desktop#add-desktop-support-to-an-existing-flutter-app to learn about adding Windows support to a project".
After i entered the given url and trying to run the command: "flutter create --platforms=window,macos,linux ." it says: "Ambiguous organization in existing files: {il.co.project.pos, com.example}. The --org command line argument must be specified to recreate project."

[Here trying to run on windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbaDC.png)

[Here trying to run the create command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdzGO.png)

Comment: Did you found a solution for this ?

Answer (score 4):

choose the package name:

package_name = com.xxx

```
flutter create --org com.xxx .
```

Answer (score 3):

run `flutter create --org your_package_name project_name`

Answer (score 3):

You can try this command in your projects root folder

```
flutter create --platforms=windows --org=com.example.org_name .
```

Answer (score 1):

For those wondering, you will also get this error by having a parent directory name using dashes like: `this-will-fail` should be: `thiswillfail`

After that run: `flutter create --org=com.project.web .`

Comment: This was my issue as well, changed the parent directory name and create command worked.

Answer (score 0):

You Probably re-use the code for new project and changed the package name that's why its causing conflict with your project
use
flutter create --org package_name .

Answer (score 0):

if you run inside terminal for web if you want for iOS then simple change web on iOS like `flutter create --platforms=web`. if then show error like this kind of error Ambiguous organization in existing files: {com.ecobuy, com.eco_buy}. The `--org` command line argument must be specified to recreate project.
then simply write below line
`flutter create --platforms=web --org=com.example.org_name`